# Any liquid metallic alloys which are safe to handle with bare hands?

Tags: metals

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_metal describes some alloys which are liquid at room temperature containing gallium, and sodium-potassium. We are advised not to handle them, and mercury, with unprotected skin. Are there any which are safe (as safe as, say, alcohol or glycerine)?

Comment: I suppose, while not a true alloy, ferrofluid (http://ask.metafilter.com/145880/Ferro-fluid-experiment-safe) is relatively harmless and has several metallic properties...